# Get Value Json RajaOngkir

Tags: php, html, json, curl

I find it difficult to get value on the results of json, if you have the answer please help me...

**this is my code** :

```
<?php
$asal = '2';
$id_kabupaten = '3';
$kurir = 'jne';
$berat = '1000';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/cost",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "origin=".$asal."&destination=".$id_kabupaten."&weight=".$berat."&courier=".$kurir."",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "key: ***********"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}?>
```

Comment: Repeating the same useless text over and over again to get around the minimum text requirements is a violation of the site guidelines. It's also extremely disrespectful to the users of this site. If you cannot be bothered to put effort into clearly explaining the problem, it's not worth our effort to try and help you. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] guidelines, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here. If the requirements of this site are too much for you to follow, feel free to go somewhere else to ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echoing out the result, instead you should [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it, then you can access its values.

**You also may want to regenerate your API key.**

```
<?php
$asal = '2';
$id_kabupaten = '3';
$kurir = 'jne';
$berat = '1000';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/cost",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "origin=".$asal."&destination=".$id_kabupaten."&weight=".$berat."&courier=".$kurir."",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "key: *********************"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    exit("cURL Error #:" . $err);
}

$response = json_decode($response);
```

`$response` will now be an object, like:

```
/*
stdClass Object
(
    [rajaongkir] => stdClass Object
        (
            [query] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [origin] => 2
                    [destination] => 3
                    [weight] => 1000
                    [courier] => jne
                )

            [status] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 200
                    [description] => OK
                )

            [origin_details] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [province_id] => 21
                    [province] => Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam (NAD)
                    [type] => Kabupaten
                    [city_name] => Aceh Barat Daya
                    [postal_code] => 23764
                )

            [destination_details] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [city_id] => 3
                    [province_id] => 21
                    [province] => Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam (NAD)
                    [type] => Kabupaten
                    [city_name] => Aceh Besar
                    [postal_code] => 23951
                )

            [results] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [code] => jne
                            [name] => Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)
                            [costs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [service] => CTC
                                            [description] => JNE City Courier
                                            [cost] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [value] => 20000
                                                            [etd] => 2-3
                                                            [note] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

) 
*/
```

Then you would access like:

```
echo $response->rajaongkir->results[0]->costs[0]->cost[0]->value;
```

Comment: error -_-
this is my code : echo $response->rajaongkir->destination_details->value;

Comment: Where is `value` in the above object? Try `echo $response->rajaongkir->destination_details->province;`

Comment: There is city_id, province_id, province, type, city_name, postal_code..

Comment: this is the result :

Comment: What value do you want from the data?

Comment: I want to take the value "value": 20000,
my code :$response->rajaongkir->results->costs->cost->value;

Comment: @safagroup use `echo $response->results[0]->costs[0]->cost[0]->value;`

Comment: not working bro -_- : this is the result : 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$results in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rajao/index.php on line 36

Comment: Sorry `echo $response->rajaongkir->results[0]->costs[0]->cost[0]->value;`

Comment: Basically can you see how it traverses the structure of the above output.

Comment: thank you very much sir already want to help me, this code work forme : 
$response->rajaongkir->results[0]->costs[0]->cost[0]->value;

Comment: yes i really understand a little about json after seeing this problem, thansk :D